# how to show multiple card in carousal

Tags: vuetify.js

Could Any one help me...I want to show cards in a carousal.In the first carousal I want three cards to be show and the second carousal I want to show only two cards. my problem is that In first carousal and second carousal total cards are shows..

```
<v-flex>
  <v-carousel hide-delimiters style="box-shadow: 0px 0px" prev-icon>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="i in 2" :key="i">
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex sm4 v-for="j in color" :key="j" pl-2 pr-2>
          <v-card :color="j">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
              <div>
                <h3 class="headline mb-0">Card {{i}}-{{j}}</h3>
                <div> Card text </div>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</v-flex>
  <script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      color: ['red','orange','green','primary','error']
    }
    }
    }
    </script
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70202529-v4251?file=/src/components/CarouselExample.vue

I assume that's because you're trying to generate the `v-carousel-item` with a `v-for`. Do you want to generate the `v-card's` dinamically? If so, you'll get the text from an array? If the cards will have static text you could simply create each carousel item manually.

[image: Carousel preview]